# Does a Blazor server-side app actually start when its application pool gets recycled?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server-side app with a timed hosted service (implements `IHostedService` with a timer). The app is hosted in IIS and has its own application pool which gets recycled one a day.

I have noticed that after the pool gets recycled, I the timed hosted service doesn't start (I'm logging the events) even though the app is actually running. Once I access the app for the very first time, the service starts as expected.

Is this normal behavior for Blazor server-side apps?

Comment: That’s normal since .NET Framework 1.0.

Comment: It's not an ASP.NET Core thing, it's an IIS thing - fortunately IIS 8.0+ has support for application "warmup" aka initialization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization - so set that up to ensure your Blazor code is already running before humans visit it.